# scroll through javascript in modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have modal in which there is  *oveflow-y* and the header is static i want to scroll down to specific text in modal but problem is scrolling is done through body while the scroller of modal doesn't move.

Here is my code:

javascript css and html respectively

```js
 setTimeout(function(){

    $("#theory_modal_body").html(body_html);
    var height_overflow = $(this).offset().top;
    var final_offset = $(".highlighted:first").offset().top - 
    height_overflow;
    $("#theory-modal").animate({
        scrollTop: final_offset
    }, 2000);
}, 3000);
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 1px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="theory-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" >
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id="theory-modal-header" class="modal-header" >
                    <h4 id="theory_modal_title" class="text-center"></h4>
                    <a id="theory-modal-judgement">Judgement</a>
                    <a id="theory-modal-cites" >Cites</a>
                    <a id="theory-modal-cited-by" >Cited By</a>
                    <a id="theory-modal-judis-download" >Court's Copy</a>
                    <a id="theory-modal-download" >Download</a>
                </div>
              <!--<div class="modal-header">-->
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#relevant"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
              <!--</div>-->
              <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
                <h5 id="theory_modal_error" class="text-center"></h5>
                <p id="theory_modal_body" >
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: so you want to scroll to element inside modal window right??

Comment: yes using scroller of modal not the body@LakshmanKambam

Comment: please provide a working code, one wich allow reproduce your issue. try running your snippet.

Comment: let me add jsfiddle link too! wait..

Comment: sure please add it

Comment: check this - http://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/wu0aheum/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fixed height for `.modal-body` - `overflow-y:auto;`  than add `.modal-dialog` overflow value to initial.

1). try this to make modal-body scrollable!

```
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:250px;
}
```

2). scroll to div element with javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.modal-body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#name").attr('topheight')
 }, 1000);
});

<div id="name" topheight="700"></div>
```

comment below if you have any questions?

Comment: this much i have already done basically my modal and body (i.e. background) both have scrollbar and when script runs it scrolls the body scrollbar i want to scroll through modal scrollbar thanks for the help

Comment: can i have working jsfiddle link for your code? you mentioned $("#theory_modal_body").html(body_html); and in body you've given id="theory-modal-header" - correct this... and where is body_html variable..i don't understand

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvksingh24/wu0aheum/15/ it is like this but in this scrolling is not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvksingh24/wu0aheum/15/ it is like this but in this scrolling is not working